# Error: La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado, en Script Personalizado de Analysis Services

Tags: visual-studio, .net, ssis, microsoft-sql

Actualmente mi script personalizado realizado en Analysis Services me da el siguiente error al ejecutarlo:
`Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ni una de sus dependencias. La definición del manifiesto del ensamblado no coincide con la referencia al ensamblado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80131040)`
Me lo da en la siguiente parte de mi programa:
`en ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows() en UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap) en Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)`, por otra parte todo la lógica del código esta bien, finalmente, ya en las parte de referencias se encuentra la respectiva referencia a **System.Text.Json en su versión 8.0.0.0** y en el GAC se agrego correctamente la librería DLL con esta respectiva versión, el problema reside en el archivo `DtsDebugHost.exe.config` ya que tiene la siguiente referencia `<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="7.0.0.3"/> <codeBase version = "7.0.0.3" href = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\..\..\MSBuild\Current\Bin\System.Text.Json.dll" /> </dependentAssembly>`, por lo que al editar manualmente esta parte y ponerle el 8.0.0.0, al recompilar la solución, se modifica automáticamente este archivo y se reintegra otra vez la referencia a la versión de la librería 7.0.0.3.